# Create a xlsx from template

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx

I have a xls template that has headers and specifies column font and color.
When adding rows, the new added cells have the desired font and color.
The same with a xlsx doesn't seem to work because the new cell loses font and color.
Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From another post it seems that getColumnStyle and setCellStyle could be the way to apply column formatting to new cells. Other suggestions are appreciated.